# Why are changes done to $scope in directive's link function not reflected on UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

AngularJS directives' `link` function change isolate scope data not reflected in UI.

Here is an example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span>Title: {{myParams.title}}</span>',
        scope: {
            myParams: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope) {
            // the new value is not reflected in ui
            $scope.myParams.title = 'this is myDirective';
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div my-directive my-params="{title: 'this is title'}"></div>
```

I want the HTML page to display `this is myDirective` but in fact it is `this is title`.

In addition, could you explain why it is displaying like this. Thanks

Comment: what is this `my-params` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the `my-params="{title: 'this is title'}"` is a *constant* expression and not assignable. So even though you try to overwrite the `'title'` property, it gets overwritten back from the constant. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lrvcvem/). It contains your code and is set to work with Angular 1.4. With the difference that the directive is used once as above and once with a changable, non-constant value from a controller:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
  <div my-directive my-params="{title: 'this is title'}"></div>
  <div my-directive my-params="data"></div>
</div>
```

The second instance (non-constant expression) works.

**Now try to change the Angular version to 1.2.** Notice that now Angular throws an infinite digest error:

```
VM1033 angular.js:9101 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}; oldVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}; oldVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}; oldVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}; oldVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}"],["fn: parentValueWatch; newVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}; oldVal: {\"title\":\"this is title\"}"]]
```

The expression given in the directive (i.e. `my-params="{title: 'this is title'}"`) is trying to overwrite the directive scope attribute (always creating a new object in 1.2, hence the infinite digest).

Answer (score 0):

The `link` function is only executed once when the `directive` is initialized.
So the value to `myParams.title` from inside the `link` function is assigned at this stage(but it would get overridden later)

After that you have updated the value of `my-params` in the attribute (which would be watched separately and updated by angular). So, the value in the attribute is the latest value for myParam.title and it is reflected in the UI.

In case, you want to set a new value, you can have a click function (or other event handler) inside `link`, which can change the value like this:

in controller:

```
$scope.myparams = {title: 'this is title'};
```

in UI:

```
<div my-directive my-params="myparams"></div>
```

in directive:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<span> Title: {{myParams.title}} </span>',
        scope: {
            myParams: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope,element) {
            // the new value is not reflected in ui

            element.click(function(){
                $scope.myParams.title = 'this is myDirective';
                $scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: because the updated value is the one provided in the attribute, the link function has already run, before the attribute value is assigned, so the attribute value is the latest value.